# Call ArangoDB docker container from a python script container fails

Tags: python, docker, arangodb, pyarango, python-arango

I have a python script that I dockerized, inside the script i make a call to ArangoDB. I have another container running an ArangoDB image. When i run both containers, I'm able to access ArangoDB on my localhost and if I run my python script from outside its container it can call ArangoDB successfully. However when i run the script from inside a docker container, it fails to connect to the containerized ArangoDB because it does not identify that there is a server up and running, i get the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/arango/client.py", line 167, in db
    raise ServerConnectionError('bad connection: {}'.format(err))
arango.exceptions.ServerConnectionError: bad connection: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8529): Max retries exceeded with url: /_db/dox/_api/collection (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f17a4db3450>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 
111] Connection refused'))
```

Here is my dockerfile for the python script

```
FROM python:3.7-buster

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "main.py" ]
```

And this is where i call ArangoDB from my python script:

```
class ArangoDB():
    def __init__(self, db, username, password):
        """
        Creates an ArangoDB session and connects to a specified Arango database.

        Parameters
        ----------
        db : str
            Arango database name
        username : str
            Arango database username
        password : str
            Arango database password

        Returns
        -------
        An instance of ArangoDB API Wrapper
        """
        logger.info(f'User {username} Connecting to database: {db}')
        self._conn = ArangoClient()
        self._db = self._conn.db(name=db, username=username, password=password,verify=True)
        logger.info(f"Successfully connected to database: {db}")
```

Finally, this is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services: 
    arangodb:
        image: arangodb:latest
        container_name: db
        environment: 
            ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD: route66
        ports:
            - "8529:8529"
        volumes:
            - arangodb_data:/var/lib/arangodb3
            - arangodb_apps_data:/var/lib/arangodb3-apps
    python:
        build: .
        depends_on: 
            - arangodb
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
        container_name: myapp
networks:
    default:
        external:
            name: back

volumes:
    arangodb_data:
    arangodb_apps_data:
```

Comment: Which endpoint are you trying to hit. Given your docker-compose file it should probably be arangodb:8529 when trying to connect from another container.

Comment: @camba1 that's quite strange, I've literally spent around 12 continuous hours trying to figure this problem out and have read and tried so many ways including what you just mentioned in your answer, I do not know why it suddenly worked now but not when I tried it before. In any case, thanks a lot! I'm so glad it's solved

Answer (score 0):

I had apache / php in a container and arangodb in a different container.

I had to use the "bridge" network that docker auto creates for all running containers.
these commands will show you what you have:
docker network ll
docker network inspect bridge:

I got the IPv4Addresss from the arangodb container. In my case it is 172.17.0.2

I had to change the endpoint to match that IP address
ArangoConnectionOptions::OPTION_ENDPOINT => 'tcp://172.17.0.2:8529',